# C++: Swapping Characters by ref

Tags: c++

I have implemented the swap via function for two numbers and this works well. However, I am now trying to swap two character strings but i receive the names in the same order. Would anybody know where I am going wrong or what I could do to have the names change positions? here is an example of the code below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void swapages (int &age1, int &age2);           
void swapname(char *person1, char *person2);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR*argv[])
{
    char person1[] = "Alex";
    char person2[] = "Toby";
    int age1 = 22;
    int age2 = 27;


    cout << endl << "Person1 is called " << person1;
    cout << " and is " << age1 << " years old." << endl;
    cout << "Person2 is called " << person2;
    cout << " and is " << age2 << " years old." << endl;

    swapname(person1,person2);
    swapages(age1,age2);
    cout << endl << "Swap names..." << endl;
    cout << endl << "Person1 is now called " << person1;
    cout << " and is " << age1 << " years old." << endl;
    cout << "Person2 is now called " << person2;
    cout << " and is " << age2 << " years old." << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void swapages(int &age1, int &age2)
{
    int tmp = age2;
    age2 = age1;
    age1 = tmp;
}

void swapname(char *person1, char *person2)
{
    char* temp = person2;
    person2 = person1;
    person1 = temp;
}
```

Comment: well, as you said, "by ref". yet I don't see any references.

Comment: To be able to modify, you must pass your `char*` pointer by  pointer (`char**`, pointer to pointer) or by reference (`char*&`, as you've done with `int`s in `swapages()`). BTW, [arrays are evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/arrays-are-evil.html), so forget it and use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: Your code would be simpler (and actually work) if you used [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) and [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) from the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged this as C++, and you are including the `<string>` header already, so why not use `std:string` instead of all those pointers and arrays?

```
void swapname(string &person1, string &person2)
{
    string temp(person2);
    person2 = person1;
    person1 = temp;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR*argv[])
{
    string person1 = "Alex";
    string person2 = "Toby";

    swapname(person1, person2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to swap pointers that are local variables of the function while you need to swap strings. So you need to copy one string into another string. Moreover the strings can have different lengths so the exact swap will be impossible. It could be done without problems if the parameters of the function would be arrays (references to arrays) of the same size. For example

```
void swap_name( char ( &lhs )[5], char ( &rhs )[5] )
{
    char tmp[5];

    std::strcpy( tmp, lhs );
    std::strcpy( lhs, rhs );
    std::strcpy( rhs, tmp );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make minor changes to get it to work the way you want it to work.

```
void swapname(char **person1, char **person2);
.
.
char *person1 = "Alex";
char *person2 = "Toby";
.
.
swapname(&person1, &person2);
.
.
```

and

```
void swapname(char **person1, char **person2)
{
    char* temp = *person2;

    *person2 = *person1;  
    *person1 = temp;    
}
```

Comment: This is C code, not C++.  You could at least use `char *&` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, person1 and person2 are defined as 2 char arrays not char pointer variables, you can not swap them, if you pass the 2 arrays into the swapname function which takes 2 pointers as parameters, it should not even compile.